# Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.contextHeadersBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9 version and Feign and Fallback.
I get a strange error when calling a single service through the Feign client.
Help, please.

My Feign config

```
@Configuration
@Import(HeaderConverter.class)
public class SecuritiesFeignConfig {
    private final HeaderConverter headerConverter;

    public SecuritiesFeignConfig(HeaderConverter headerConverter) {
        this.headerConverter = headerConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> headerConverter.getCallContextHeaders().forEach(requestTemplate::header);
    }

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(customObjectMapper());
        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(objectFactory));
    }

    private ObjectMapper customObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

and my main config class in app

```
@Configuration
@Import(FiltersConfig.class)
public class frameworkConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MSACallContextImpl callContext() {
        return new MSACallContextImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CallContextCreator callContextCreator() {
        return new CallContextCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public ContextHeadersBuilder contextHeadersBuilder(MSACallContextImpl callContextImpl) {
        return new ContextHeadersBuilder(callContextImpl);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

But when I try to make a service call through the Feign client, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.contextHeadersBuilder': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Comment: You are using a scope where yu shouldn't be using one.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean this: @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  ?

Comment: The bean you are using the `ContextHeadersBuilder` is used by a component that isn't scoped to a request. Hence mkaing this bean request scoped won't work. Why does it need to be request scoped in the first place?

Comment: if I will replace "request" to "singleton" - it works for me. But in this case we lose context =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the current problem.
Need to add into the application properties file

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 6000
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems like Bean creation is not taking place and the @Autowired is not able to create the OBJECT so try
@Service Annotation will be missing as it worked for me when i put @Service Annotation in Class level